# Include php files with referenced includes, when they are in different folders

Tags: php, reference, require

I have put most of my pages in the root folder of my project itself.
And a few files like `config.php`, `initialize.php`, `helpers.php` etc are in a folder in the root.

Let me  show the folder tree

```
user
    view.php
    manage.php

config 
    config.php

core
   initialize.php

index.php
login.php
```

I have included files like `config/config.php`, `Core/initialize.php` etc. in the files that are in root folder like

```
<?php require_once('core/initialize.php'); ?>
```

where the **initialize.php** again **includes  config.php** like

```
<?php require_once('config/config.php'); ?>
```

and they work fine

But, I have View.php and manage.php where i had to use referenced includes like

```
<?php require_once('../core/initialize.php'); ?>
```

but then, the absolute require methods in the config.php breaks and It is everywhere.

If i change it from absolute to referenced in config.php, the view.php works and index.php fails.

Anyone having any idea about it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
$base = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
require($base . "/index.php");
require($base . "/user/view.php");
```

Comment: doesn't this depend on the file where we place it? like if we are in `user/view.php`, the `dirname` will be the/path/to/user/view.php

Answer (score 0):

All `includes` or `require`s should be from the perspective of `index.php` - if that's where you're calling them from. So, since `view.php` will be run from "within" `index.php` then the `require` in view should be

```
<?php require_once('core/initialize.php'); ?>
```